# random quote machine code:The WebDev Coach (youtube)-error shows for this.selectedQuote in render() function

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Button from './components/Button';
import random from 'lodash';

class App extends Component {

    super(props) {
        constructor(props)
        this.state =
            {
                quotes: [],
                selectedQuoteIndex: null,
            }
        this.selectQuoteIndex = this.selectQuoteIndex.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/natebass/b0a548425a73bdf8ea5c618149fe1fce/raw/f4231cd5961f026264bb6bb3a6c41671b044f1f4/quotes.json')
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(quotes => this.setState({quotes}))
            .then(() => this.setState({selectedQuoteIndex: this.selectQuoteIndex()}))
    }

    nextQuoteClickHandler() {
        console.log("click");
    }

    selectQuoteIndex() {
        if (!this.state.quotes.length) {
            return;
        }
        return random(0, this.state.quotes.length - 1)
    }

    get selectedQuote() {
        if (!this.state.quotes.length || !Number.isInteger(this.state.selectQuoteIndex)) {
            return;
        }
        return this.state.quotes[this.state.selectedQuoteIndex];
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App" id="quote-box">
                <Button buttonDisplayName="next click!" clickHandler={this.nextQuoteClickHandler}/>
                {this.selectedQuote ? this.selectedQuote.quote : ''}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to you Stack Overflow - what is your question here?

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return random;
}
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      quotes: [],
      selectedQuoteIndex: null
    }
    this.selectQuoteIndex = this.selectQuoteIndex.bind(this);
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/natebass/b0a548425a73bdf8ea5c618149fe1fce/raw/f4231cd5961f026264bb6bb3a6c41671b044f1f4/quotes.json')
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(quotes => this.setState({ quotes: quotes }))
      .then(() => this.setState({ selectedQuoteIndex: this.selectQuoteIndex() }));
  }

  nextQuoteClickHandler() {
    this.setState({
      selectedQuoteIndex: getRandomNumber(1, this.state.selectedQuoteIndex)
    })


  }

  selectQuoteIndex() {
    if (!this.state.quotes.length) {
      return;
    }
    return getRandomNumber(1, this.state.quotes.length - 1)
  }

  render() {
    console.log('index', this.state.selectedQuoteIndex)
    return (
      <div className="App" id="quote-box">
        <button onClick={() => this.nextQuoteClickHandler()} >next click!</button>
        <p>{this.state.selectedQuoteIndex ? this.state.quotes[this.state.selectedQuoteIndex].quote : ''}</p>
      </div>
    );

  }

}

export default App;
```

The function `getRandomNumber()` generates random numbers but after some time it starts generating the same numbers.

Comment: After about 3 or 4 clicks the program stops working and doesn't display any more quotes.  Not sure why. (thanks for help so far).

Comment: I have edited the answer, the problem was when the selectedQuoteIndex becomes zero it shows the empty string, so now I'm generating random numbers starting from 0.